# Unity - Export from Mac to Windows not running as well

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, windows-10

I've been developing a game for Mac and PC on my Mac. Whenever I build my game to OSX it runs nice and smoothly but when I build my game to Windows 10 it runs pretty slow and has frequent lag spikes that make the game near unplayable. I presume there is some problem with Unity converting my game from Mac to Windows but if anyone knows how I can fix this it would be much appreciated if you could let me know.

Many Thanks,

Tommy

Comment: Have you tried creating a build with the debug option "autoconnect profiler" enabled?

Comment: I haven't tried doing that no. What does the auto connect profiler do and how can I use it?

Comment: It connects a build to the Editor so that you can view the performance statistics (Window -> Profiler).  That will let you know what's taking up so much cpu/gpu time so you can optimize/fix it.

Comment: I presume that means I will have to use Unity on my PC to run it - I use Unity on my Mac is there any way I can fix it from there? I presume the error is something to do with how Unity converts the code.

Comment: As long as both computers are on the same network, it should work.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try that then I'll get back to you.

Comment: Nevermind, I've fixed it. I just needed to update Unity. Sorry for the late reply and thank you for all your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, all I needed was to update Unity to the latest version.